# cmake error - cannot find opencv libraries or headers

Tags: opencv, cmake, aruco

I've set the opencv environment variable and updated the path but I'm still getting an error when I try to make the opencv aruco library with cmake gui on windows - the error says

"OpenCV required but some headers or libs not found. Please specify OpenCV directory using OpenCV_DIR env. variable"

I've looked at the FindOpenCV.cmake file where the error is coming from, but I can't tell what part is causing an error and was wondering if anyone else has had similar problems or knows how to fix it it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just check which cache variables are set to NOTFOUND.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that? I tried deleting the cmakecache file that's generated when the cmake is unsuccessful, and have also tried starting with a fresh copy of the folder after changing all the environment variables if that's what you meant?

Comment: When CMake successfully searches library or include directory, it sets cache variable to corresponded path. But if the search has been failed, same variable is set to value with `-NOTFOUND` suffix. By looking (`grep`'ing) into the CMake cache, you can found variables with such values. Knowing names of these variables, you may trace their origin in the script `findOpenCV.cmake`. Moreover, very often you can *guess* what  is going wrong using only names of such variables or their description.

Answer (score 0):

@DeirdreMeehan are you getting error as shown in the following image? 
[image]

If this is the same error you are getting then you are supposed to link openCV directory from your computer to ArUco. That is you add OpenCV path in to value field where the name field is "OpenCV_DIR".